# Server Cluster Design/Setup

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, cluster, cloud-computing

OK So I am not sure if this is posted already but let me explain my goal and what I am trying to do. Really need some help on this as I am not really linux or server savvy yet. I know the basics with SSH and things like that but nothing advanced.

So my goal is to have this:

2 Virtual Machines (Cloud from SingleHop.com) for the web front end.
1 Database Virtual Machine (Cloud from SingleHop.com) for the MySQL Database.
1 Virtual Machine for a Load Balancing Software such as HaProxy (http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)

I would be using Linux for these machines.

So I am wanting to have a nice redundant server setup like such. How would I go about doing this? I would first deploy all these 4 machines from SingleHop.com. Then once they're ready to go, I would install HaProxy onto the one machine, configure it to balance the 2 web front end virtual machines. I would need cPanel installed on at least the 2 Virtual Machines so I can manage the websites easier. I'm not sure but cPanel does have remote database connection tools so maybe I would be able to use that for some of it?

Anyways, like I said, I just need some help with designing a cluster setup like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is really much too broad for this site. Serverfault is not a how-to site, and we don't take kindly to people asking us to do their jobs for them. I'd recommend heeding the warning I give in my answer below, and then coming back with **specific**, well-defined questions as you're working through this.

Comment: ErikA, I never asked for the members of this site to do jobs for me, did I? Nope. I am asking for advice and tips on the best way to do this type of setup. Please re-read the post and make sure you understand it before judging my post. My post is simply asking for advice on how I would go about doing a setup like this, not asking for a step by step guide of how to do it. Some people may know things I am not aware of so thats why I posted.

Comment: My comment stands - this is not an advice site, nor is it a discussion forum. Like I stated, come back when you have a specific, well-researched, well-defined question and we'll be glad to give you the best answer we can come up with. Serverfault (and it's other Stackexchange siblings) are just not geared to deal with discussion-type correspondence required by "advice" questions.

Comment: The "I am not really linux or server savvy yet" part is the kiss of death for the question. ServerFault is for people who *are* server savvy and just need some help along the way. Other forums and communities are better for those who are just beginning. The Q/A nature of the site (in contrast to a true forum) means that the best kinds of questions are those that are to-the-point and not open-ended or chatty.

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you is this - you admit that you're not a very experienced linux sysadmin. As such, you need to *start simple*. You need to get your head around managing a single linux server before you can venture into managing several like this in a complex configuration.

All things considered, this is not a very complex setup, but for a new admin like yourself, you'll find it to be quickly overwhelming.

Comment: Nothing to admit. I already said I know the basics and have talked to several hosting companies about the best ways to do this and this is what I feel is the best type of setup.

Answer (score 1):

A standard setup would usually have two load-balancer VMs to eliminate a point of failure as right now you have two, the load balancer and the database.

I agree with ErikA in that you need to start small.   Stay far away from cpanel or any other web frontend.  Once you figure out how to deploy a single apache/nginx/PHP/rails/python app from scratch you can worry about deploying a highly available and durable infrastructure.